# Enforce a specific type of a key based on the value of another key in the object (Discriminated unions)

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union, union-types

Maybe the title of the question wasn't so explicit what about I want, but what I want is something called *discrimnated unions*, I think. It's documented here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions

A have a type A, with two fields, B and C, the type of the field B is well-defined set of string literals and I want that the type of C be in reason of the value from the field B.

Some code to better explain:

```
type Field1Values = "a" | "b" | "c";

type TypeForValueA = {
   ...
}

type TypeForValueB = {
   ...
}

type TypeForValueC = {
   ...
}

type RootType = {
    field1: Field1Values,
    field2: <something here that I didn't know exactly what to put>
}


const objA: RootType = {
    field1: "a",
    field2: {
        // Only the values from the type TypeForValueA are allowed
    }

}

const objB: RootType = {
    field1: "b",
    field2: {
        // Only the values from the type TypeForValueB are allowed
    }

}
```

How can I achieve the effect that I want?

Thanks

Edit:

I already tried like in the docs

```
type NetworkState =
  | NetworkLoadingState
  | NetworkFailedState
  | NetworkSuccessState;
```

And the lint shows me all the fields from all the types, I want that only the fields from the correct type be shown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created [a playground link demonstrating an answer](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcE8AcFNQGIEtYBsAmBGAagQ1QK6wDOoAvKAES6WgA+VARrQ5QMaUDcoIoAdgHtQqAXwDmsAE79YsdHICwAKGVQ4oACoxYCAZLyFYAQXKgA3stBWAZigy7JRgFyhi4SUnGdlAX2WrtTW0HAyIAIVMLJStQWzR0BzCXPgIAW0YpbyU-FSU1eC04EPwiAGFIyxs7BL1Sl0YBAVRYXD4snID1ACVG8BMKKJjY6swXai5KqviAJhdCnT1Q43bO+B6BcAiByeH40aYJ6Ji4jFmgosWS2DCVvMD18HLto6mMffZDoZP0M-niw1Kt3yoAe81MDxMDAeEShvUB-lybFEblAAkYACtnCDemDnl8RmMaAAaHa8b5naCSEikAAGbHcqAA1MRoLg2LAabE9K4CGIJG4kMjfMokXwUWj0UlsRtceYdt93swSS8eGByS5KdTQHSGczWezOdZucRefzwIKxcKlKLxRi6tLwLLBscCVQOMqhmTqhSqcRafTJEyWWyOVzpCa+SRzULskA).

The problem with your original approach is that it doesn't communicate any mapping between the discriminating field's set of possible values and the discriminated field's possible set of types. All I did was adapt your example to follow the TypeScript docs you linked.

```js
// type Field1Values = "a" | "b" | "c"; // no longer needed

type TypeForValueA = {
   fieldForA: string;
}

type TypeForValueB = {
   fieldForB: number;
}

type TypeForValueC = {
   fieldForC: boolean;
}

type RootA = {
    field1: "a";
    field2: TypeForValueA;
}
type RootB = {
    field1: "b";
    field2: TypeForValueB;
}
type RootC = {
    field1: "c";
    field2: TypeForValueC;
}
type RootType = RootA | RootB | RootC;


const objA: RootType = {
    field1: "a",
    // field2: press `ctrl+space` for suggestions
}
const objB: RootType = {
    field1: "b",
    // field2: press `ctrl+space` for suggestions
}
const objC: RootType = {
    field1: "c",
    // field2: press `ctrl+space` for suggestions
}
```